# Ionic user authentication with firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase

I created a user login template. I want to sign up user with firebase.

I am getting the below error.

Error: Firebase.createUser failed: First argument must contain the key "email" with type "string"
    at Error (native)

My controller

```
.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$firebaseAuth','$scope','$timeout','$stateParams',function($firebaseAuth,$scope, $timeout, $stateParams) {
    console.log("Login Control");
$scope.signupEmail = function() {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://requestmaker.firebaseio.com");
    ref.createUser({
        email: $scope.email,
        password: $scope.password
    }, function(error, userData) {
        if (error) {
            console.log("Error creating user:", error);
        } else {
            console.log("Successfully created user account with uid:", userData.uid);
        }
    });

};
```

}]);

..In my index.html file, I have included

```
 <!-- firebase.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.3.2/firebase.js"></script>


    <!-- AngularFire -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/1.1.2/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

..In my ionic view template

```
 <button class="button button-full button-assertive" ng-click="signupEmail()">Login</button>
```

Some one please tell me where I am wrong.

### Answer

.controller('SignInCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicHistory, Auth, UserData, $firebase) {

```
        $scope.hideBackButton = true;

        /* FOR DEV PURPOSES */
        $scope.user = {
            email: "",
            password: ""
        };

        $scope.signIn = function (user) {

            $rootScope.show('Logging In...');

            /* Check user fields*/
            if(!user.email || !user.password){
                $rootScope.hide();
                $rootScope.notify('Error','Email or Password is incorrect!');
                return;
            }

            /* All good, let's authentify */
            Auth.$authWithPassword({
                email    : user.email,
                password : user.password
            }).then(function (authData) {
                console.log(authData);
                $rootScope.hide();
            }).catch(function (error) {
                $rootScope.hide();
                $rootScope.notify('Error','Email or Password is incorrect!');
            });
        };
```

Thanks,
Sabarisri

Comment: What is the value of $scope.email?

Comment: @AndréKool it is a scope variable i have in my template.html

Comment: Can you add the code where you set the email and password? I think they don't have the correct type since the error is saying you need an email of type string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.controller('SignInCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state, $ionicHistory, Auth, UserData, $firebase) {

```
    $scope.hideBackButton = true;

    /* FOR DEV PURPOSES */
    $scope.user = {
        email: "",
        password: ""
    };

    $scope.signIn = function (user) {

        $rootScope.show('Logging In...');

        /* Check user fields*/
        if(!user.email || !user.password){
            $rootScope.hide();
            $rootScope.notify('Error','Email or Password is incorrect!');
            return;
        }

        /* All good, let's authentify */
        Auth.$authWithPassword({
            email    : user.email,
            password : user.password
        }).then(function (authData) {
            console.log(authData);
            $rootScope.hide();
        }).catch(function (error) {
            $rootScope.hide();
            $rootScope.notify('Error','Email or Password is incorrect!');
        });
    };
```